# What is the Hd output of SoX’s play?

Tags: sox

When I use the `play` command provided by *SoX*, sometimes the playback information contains a number labeled *Hd*, which the manpage doesn’t seem to mention. What does it mean?

```
$ play song.mp3
In:72.5% 00:04:43.38 [00:01:47.73] Out:12.5M [  -===|====  ] Hd:4.3 Clip:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this thread on the SoX mailing list: [[SoX-users] What does Hd:0.0 mean?](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/mailman/message/29195740/):

The first [answer](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/mailman/message/29195846/) is:

> Rene Maurer <renemaur@...>:
>
> > Can anyone tell me what "Hd:" means. Playing songs let this value
> >     change from time to time (Hd:0.0,  Hd:1.6, Hd:4.9, Hd:0.0 for
> >     example).
>
> It's the headroom in dB (in case you speak German:
>   Aussteuerungsreserve), i.e. how much the output signal could be
>   amplified before clipping occurs. It is only shown if it is relatively
>   low, so that there is risk to hit the ceiling.
>
> The progress indicator is described in more detail in connection with
>   the -S global option in the manpage.
>
> Ulrich

Answer (score 2):

Use the source, Luke:

Looking at line 1271 in [sox.c](https://github.com/chirlu/sox/blob/master/src/sox.c), this value is produced by a call to the function `headroom()`, which, looking at line 1248, prints `min_headroom`, which is a number in `dB`.

That means it's the [headroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headroom_%28audio_signal_processing%29) as used in audio signal processing.